# Retrieving Sent Email ID from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, .net, email, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm currently using the Microsoft Graph API to send emails in a .NET application. My current code to send an email looks like this:

```
await client.Users[model.From]
            .SendMail(message, true)
            .Request()
            .PostAsync(cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This successfully sends the email, but the `SendMail` function doesn't return any direct information about the sent email, and specifically, it doesn't give me the `Id` of the sent email. I need to keep track of this ID for later use in my application.

I've looked into fetching the most recent email from the 'Sent Items' folder after the `SendMail` function call, but I'm worried about the reliability of this approach:

```
var sentItems = await client.Users[model.From]
                            .MailFolders["SentItems"]
                            .Messages
                            .Request()
                            .Top(1)
                            .OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc")
                            .GetAsync();

string messageId = sentItems.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault()?.Id;
```

I also thought about manually setting the email id, but from my understanding, this field is ignored and assigned automatically from the server side.

Is there any other way to retrieve the ID of the sent email directly from the SendMail operation?

Comment: Don't wait for Graph to generate the id for you, add a unique property to the email before you send it so you can identify it afterwards. (A custom property, not the built-in id)

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson can you tell me how to do that in the SDK?

Comment: If the subject of the mail is unique then you can add filter to your query: await client.Users[model.From].MailFolders["SentItems"].Messages                          .Request().Filter("subject eq 'unique subject'").Top(1)                           .OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc").GetAsync(); But still not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using SendMail you can create a Draft message, get the ID and then Send it. You'll probably also want to make the message ID imutable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. This worked flawlessly. To anyone interested this is how you can make a draft immutable:

```await userRequestBuilder.Messages.Request().Header("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"").AddAsync(message, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)```